# How to do database migration if SQLite is used?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

My app is on App Store and in its new version I have updated the schema, like number of columns has been changed and name of columns has been changed. But now when I uploaded the new version on App Store, the app is crashing.

I came to know that this is happening because I have changed the schema. I have use SQLite so is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Your db already exists in the old app version. That's why it's crashing. So, you should delete the old db and create this new db through code.

Comment: @user1025560 Can you please explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports a 'version' when you open (or create) the DB.  This is a unique value that you decide.  When you change the schema you should change the 'version' string so that the old database is abandoned for a new one.  In the same way you would handle creating the database on first setup, you must then also manually migrate any important data from the previous database to the new one.

Unfortunately there's no way to role back an app to the last good version, the best you can do is to remove your app from the store for a few days until you get a fix into place.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try like this.

   1. Check the version
   2. If new then - if you want Fetch all data from old DB
        and remove the old DB.    else
        no changes
   3. Create new db
   4. Insert data what get from old DB

      ```
      NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

      BOOL dbSuccess = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

      if (dbSuccess) {
          NSDictionary *oldDetailsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:writablePath];

          if(![[oldDetailsDict valueForKey:@"version"] isEqualToString:Current_APP_VERSION]){
              NSString *oldVersion = [oldDetailsDict valueForKey:@"version"];
              if ([oldVersion isEqualToString:Current_APP_VERSION]) {
                  //no code change needed

              }else{
                  //Get data from old db
                  //Data moved to array
                  NSArray *oldDataArray = [Product getDataFromDatabase];  

                  //Remove the old Database
                  NSString *deletePath  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.sqlite"];
                  [fileManager removeItemAtPath:deletePath error:nil];

                  //Create the new DB for new version
                  [self createdatabase];

                  //Again Insert the old data to new db
                  for (Product *pro in oldDataArray) {
                      [pro insertToDB];
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      ```