# DB Structure Changed in iOS Application Update

Tags: ios, sqlite

My iOS application contains an sqlite DB which holds user data. Now I want to give an update to the application; problem is that new application having different DB structure. I want to transfer the details from old application DB (if exists) to new DB. For fresh installation I dont have issues.

Thanks
Augustine P A

Answer (score 1):

You must migrate your data. Check those links for how to do this:

http://cases.azoft.com/database-migration-ios-applications/

http://maniacdev.com/2013/09/tool-that-generates-the-xcdatamodel-for-migrating-sqlite-databases-to-core-data

[How to do database migration if SQLite is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734850/how-to-do-database-migration-if-sqlite-is-used)

If there are minor changes in database you can use light migration by creating a new xcdatamodelbased on previous one.